# How to use anchors in Symfony routing?

Tags: symfony, url, symfony-routing

I have defined a route as followed in my routing.yml file :

```
route_name:
    path: "/dashboard#messages/{id}"
```

However when I ask Symfony to generate that route, I get :

```
/dashboard%23messages/12345
```

How can I skip the encoding part of the route generation? Or how can I escape the `#` char in the path definition?

PS : Working with a (big) legacy system, I **cannot change** the urls.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Available from Symfony 3.2.**

Support for anchors has been announced for the routing component using the `fragment` variable :

```
$this->get('router')->generate('user_settings', ['_fragment' => 'password']);
```

Will generate an url : `/user/settings#password`

For more information [view the announcement](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-2-routing-improvements).

Comment: With [KnpMenuBundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenuBundle): `$node->addChild('settings', ['route' => 'user_settings', 'routeParameters' =>['_fragment' => 'password']])`

Answer (score 2):

You cannot easily - route parts are encoded unconditionally:

```
$url = strtr(rawurlencode($url), $this->decodedChars);
```

see at https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Generator/UrlGenerator.php#L192

Technically you might have extended the class `UrlGenerator` class and swap them using `router.options.generator_class` parameter. Then you could override the `doGenerate` method and replace `%23` -> `#`.

Comment: The only part I am concerned with is the url generation. Not the url handling.

Answer (score 2):

In twig

```
<a href="{{ path('user_settings', { '_fragment': 'password' }) }}">
```