# Internal Link with Parameters in Twig

Tags: php, html, symfony, twig, href

I want to write this:

```
{{ path('article_show', { 'slug': article.slug }) }}
```

but for a internal link, like:

```
<a href="#ID_name">...</a>
```

in html, and also by passing one o more parameters.

I use Twig in one Symfony 4 proyect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use anchors in Symfony routing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36910829/how-to-use-anchors-in-symfony-routing)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass as many arguments as you want, like `array`:

```
{{ path('article_show', {'slug': article.slug, 'param': article.param, ...}) }}
```

Comment: I know that. On the other hand this solution: $this->get('router')->generate('user_settings', ['_fragment' => 'password']); reload the page and I just want a simple twig solution to move inside the page.